# Enable macos screen recording from Terminal on macOS 11 Big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-big-sur

I would like to enable screen recording from mac terminal.

From the UI it looks like this:

[Enable screen recording from UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoURA.png)

The setting is set to false and I want to enable it from the terminal.

The only related command I found was `tccutil reset ScreenCapture [com.WHATEVERBUNDLE.YOURAPPID]`

But this resets the screen recording option and I want to enable it.

Is it possible?